# ReDirect Tomcat 9 and IIS with direct URL

Tags: windows, tomcat, redirect, iis, ajp

The setup is on a windows server 2019:
Tomcat 9.0.38, test application is up an running
Part of my server.xml config file:

```
    <Connector
    address="x.x.x.x"
    port="8000" 
    URIEncoding="UTF-8" 
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
    connectionTimeout="20000" 
    redirectPort="8443" 
    compression="on" 
    compressionMinSize="1024" 
    noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" 
    compressibleMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/css,text/plain,text/javascript, image/jpeg"
    server="Tomcat"/>

    <Connector
    protocol="AJP/1.3" 
    address="x.x.x.x" 
    port="8009" 
    redirectPort="8443" 
    tomcatAuthentication="false" 
    secretRequired="false" 
    packetSize="65536" />
```

IIS is als working fine

```
Add Virtual Directory...
-> Jakarta
```

Connector is also configured (isapi_redirect.dll)

```
    worker.list=local 
    worker.local.type=ajp13
    worker.local.host=x.x.x.x
    worker.local.port=8009
    worker.local.max_packet_size=65536

    /test/*=local
    /test=local
```

Now I am able to access the application via the "url/test" but i want to access the application only by the "url".
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

What does url/test mean? shouldn’t test be part of the url, or is your url referring to the hostname? if so, you can try to use url rewrite.

More information about url rewrite you can refer to this link: [url rewrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).

If you have difficulty creating url rule, then you can explain your needs in detail, and I can write a demo for you.

Try this rule:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^test$" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}" />
</rule>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I mean, right now i am able to access the application by:

```
http://blabla.loc/test
```

but I want to access the application only by:

```
http://blabla.loc
```

Comment: I edited my answer above, if it helps you, please mark the answer so that it can help others with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is probably not the best, but is working
I changed the folder / application from test to root and now i am able to access the application directly

Comment: Please mark the answer so that it can help others with similar problems.